# How do I port this current DNS/IIS configuration to AWS EC2 with ELB

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

This is my current DNS table

```
www.mydomain.com    A    xxx.xxx.xxx.1
*.mydomain.com      A    xxx.xxx.xxx.2
```

and inside IIS I have two sites:

- one with the bindings:

  - `http:*:80:xxx.xxx.xxx.1`
  - `https:*:443:xxx.xxx.xxx.1`
- another with the bindings:

  - `http:*:80:xxx.xxx.xxx.2`
  - `https:*:443:xxx.xxx.xxx.2`

There is a single, wildcard SSL bound to both sites.

The objective is to have a single site responding to the `www` subdomain, and another site that response to all other subdomains.

How do I achieve this in EC2 with and ELB, when I can only address the LB by hostname, and therefore `CNAME`?

Can I do this:  (is it the best way?)

Have two LBs, one for `www` and one for `*` then map their internal `routes` to different ports for the different sites, and CNAME the `www` and `*` to the different LBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to utilize Amazon's Route 53 service to load balance by IPs.  They essentially host DNS records for you.

Comment: ah that sounds better, will investigate. ta

Comment: didnt like the idea of routing by cookies anyway

Comment: hmmm... any tips? cant seem to grok how to do this

Comment: The way I understand it is that you setup DNS Aliases in Route 53.  You can then point aliases to ELB instances. Check this FAQ out: http://brntpb.st/Sy7QQv

Comment: ok thanks, Aliases look like they solve my DNS problem, but how do I share the certificate across different IIS sites? they need a unique ip/port.

Comment: Install the wildcard cert on both servers then.  If you need to have a single IIS box running two different IPs and sites but both need to be secured do a simple search for `IIS SSL Host Headers` that should take care of it.  Should be standard IIS config from here. If not you should open another question, its not usually good to post multiple questions as one massive question.

Comment: TIL two IIS bindings: `https:*:443:<ip>` and `https:hostname:443:<ip>` can co-exist on the same ip. except if you remove one, that pesky IIS bug removes the other. grr